# Excel macro store value of vlookup and then add them up

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

So I have the following sheet setup:

`Sheet 1
A        B     C
Tomatoes  100   50
Onions    20    0
Garlic    10    0 
Chicken   0     100 
Cheese    0     20`

Where each column after A is a recipe and going down is the amount of grams required in the recipe of the ingredient.

Sheet 2 has cost per 100 grams per ingredient like so:

`A         B
Chicken   10
Tomatoes  1.5
Onions    2.25`

What I'd like to do, is at the bottom of sheet 1 (ideally) under each column I could have the cost for the recipe.

In my mind it's broken down into 2 steps. Step 1 is do a vlookup from Sheet 1 to replace the grams to cost. Then do a sum of the entire column. I just don't know how to do that either in a macro or formula.

Comment: Can `Onions` appear multiple times in Column A?

Answer (score 2):

Refer the below specified link,

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/05/excel-vlookup-sum-sumif/#lookup-sum

You can download their worksheet [here](https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/vlookup-sum/xls/sum-lookup.xlsx)

Comment: I saw that link, but was having trouble understanding exactly how it would work in my Scenario.